# How do I fetch htmlcode from a url with a colon ":" in the url?

Tags: python, urllib

I've been successful in retrieving the html code in regular webpages using python and the urllib2 module.

But when I try using it with a webpage that has a colon it doesn't work. 
This code:

```
f = urllib2.urlopen("http://http://gulasidorna.eniro.se/hitta:svenska+kyrkan/")
htmlcode = f.read()
print htmlcode
```

The following code generates this error message.

```
File "/Users/jonathan/Documents/Dropbox/Python/eniro.py", line 137, in <module>
  f = urllib2.urlopen("http://http://gulasidorna.eniro.se/hitta:svenska+kyrkan/")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 394, in open
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 412, in _open
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1199, in http_open
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1140, in do_open
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 693, in _init_
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 718, in _set_hostport
httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: ''
```

Comment: Perhaps the error is in the address. Take another look and see if you can spot it: `http://http://gulasidorna.eniro.se/hitta:svenska+kyrkan/`

Comment: Shouldn't the address be `http://gulasidorna.eniro.se/hitta:svenska+kyrkan/`

Comment: I feel so humiliated. Sometimes you do the most stupid of mistakes. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Happens to all of us. Don't sweat it.

Comment: However, the source code when doing the python interpretation is different from when you check the source code in a browser. I would like to get the same source code as I get when I check it in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, you have an extra **http://** in the start of the url:

```
f = urllib2.urlopen("http://gulasidorna.eniro.se/hitta:svenska+kyrkan/")
htmlcode = f.read()
print htmlcode
```